# Can I change TVMLKit formTemplate keyboard color?

Tags: javascript, styles, tvos, tvml

I'm using a modal formTemplate to get password from an user and I'm getting problems, because the background is darker and I haven't found a way to change the color of the keyboard via TVML.

There is nothing in the Apple docs about that, but it is a real necessity.

Anyone had the same problem?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement your own formTemplate with TVMLKit because TVML has very limited features (I think you cannot just change colour of the keyboard)